# Animation "freez" in background after second MouseDown in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation

I am trying to implement a custom control button in WPF, inspired from material design. On holding down the button, there should be a growing circle from where you clicked it. I successfully implemented that in the code below, but after a second button hold (mouse down), the animation is frozen.

XAML:

```
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:LiteWpfControls"
    xmlns:Converters="clr-namespace:LiteWpfControls.Converters"
    xmlns:ed="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/drawing">

    <Converters:ArithmeticConverter x:Key="ArithmeticConverter"/>
    <Converters:ColorConverter x:Key="ColorConverter"/>

    <Style x:Key="FocusVisual">
        <Setter Property="Control.Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <Rectangle Margin="2" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Stroke="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}" StrokeThickness="1" StrokeDashArray="1 2"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Background" Color="#e67e22"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Static.Foreground" Color="White"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Pressed.Background" Color="#FFC4E5F6"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Background" Color="#FFF4F4F4"/>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="Button.Disabled.Foreground" Color="#FF838383"/>

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type local:MaterialButton}">
        <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Background}"/>
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource Button.Static.Foreground}"/>
        <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0"/>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalContentAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="1"/>
        <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="IsDefault" Value="True"/>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type local:MaterialButton}">
                    <ControlTemplate.Resources>

                        <Storyboard x:Key="sbLoader">
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames RepeatBehavior="Forever" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ed:Arc.StartAngle)" Storyboard.TargetName="arcLoading">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="360"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                            <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames RepeatBehavior="Forever" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(ed:Arc.EndAngle)" Storyboard.TargetName="arcLoading">
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="180"/>
                                <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0.5" Value="540"/>
                            </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                        </Storyboard>

                    </ControlTemplate.Resources>

                    <Grid Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" Height="{TemplateBinding Height}" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}">
                        <Border x:Name="bdrBorder" SnapsToDevicePixels="true" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                            CornerRadius="{Binding ActualHeight, ConverterParameter=/2, Converter={StaticResource ArithmeticConverter}, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding CornerRadius.BottomLeft, ElementName=bdrBorder}"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="{Binding CornerRadius.BottomRight, ElementName=bdrBorder}"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="80*"/>
                                    <RowDefinition Height="10*"/>
                                </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                <Border x:Name="bdrBorderBg" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="3" CornerRadius="{Binding CornerRadius, ElementName=bdrBorder}">
                                    <Border.Background>
                                        <RadialGradientBrush x:Name="bshBorderBg" GradientOrigin="{Binding Center, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" MappingMode="Absolute" RadiusY="{Binding RadiusX, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" RadiusX="0">
                                            <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="#55000000"/>
                                            <GradientStop Offset="0.5" Color="{Binding Background, ConverterParameter=tc0, Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}, ElementName=bdrBorder}"/>
                                        </RadialGradientBrush>
                                    <Border.Background>
                                </Border>

                                <ContentPresenter x:Name="cpContent" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                                VerticalAlignment="Center" Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"/>
                                <Border x:Name="bdrPressed" Width="0" Background="#40000000" SnapsToDevicePixels="true"
                                CornerRadius="{Binding ActualHeight, ConverterParameter=/2, Converter={StaticResource ArithmeticConverter}, Mode=OneWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
                                Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.Column="1"/>
                                <Grid Grid.RowSpan="3" Grid.ColumnSpan="3">
                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="17.5*"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="65*"/>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="17.5*"/>
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <ed:Arc x:Name="arcLoading" Opacity="0" Stroke="{TemplateBinding Foreground}" EndAngle="180" Stretch="None" StartAngle="0" Width="{Binding ActualHeight, ElementName=arcLoading}" SnapsToDevicePixels="True" Grid.Row="1"/>
                                </Grid>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="bdrBorder" Value="{Binding Background, ConverterParameter=lc50, Converter={StaticResource ColorConverter}, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:MaterialButton}}}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                        <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="bdrBorder" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Background}"/>
                            <Setter Property="TextElement.Foreground" TargetName="cpContent" Value="{StaticResource Button.Disabled.Foreground}"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>

</ResourceDictionary>
```

Part of the code:

```
protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var aniPressed = new DoubleAnimation(0, ActualWidth, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 500));
    bshBorderBg.Center = e.GetPosition(this);
    bshBorderBg.BeginAnimation(RadialGradientBrush.RadiusXProperty, aniPressed);

    base.OnMouseUp(e);
}

protected override void OnMouseUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var aniFade = new DoubleAnimation(1, 0, new TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0, 400));
    bshBorderBg.BeginAnimation(RadialGradientBrush.OpacityProperty, aniFade);

    base.OnMouseUp(e);
}
```

I would like to know where i went wrong. By the way, i just migrated from WinForms to the awesomeness of WPF.

Comment: Try to first cancel your previous animations

Comment: removed all the animations... still the same

Comment: how did you cancelled the previous animations?

Comment: completely removed the triggers both in xaml and code

Comment: no, that's not what I mean, the animations previously triggered in OnMouseUp and OnMouseDown still can be executing, you need to store these animations to be able to cancel them before executing a new one or they will mix

Comment: damn, as easy as that, thanks mate